# MySQL query - Filtering by date and id

Tags: mysql, filter

I have a table and I want to get:

```
ID  Name    Stock   Code    Date
<---------------------------------------------->
123 GAME_0011     1     WK1 2018-11-20 16:12:16
120 GAME_0088     212   WK1 2018-11-20 19:32:13
109 GAME_0088     21    WK1 2018-11-20 19:32:13
101 GAME_0088     20    WK1 2018-11-20 14:00:41
105 GAME_0011     1     WK1 2018-11-20 14:00:41
102 GAME_0088     2     WK1 2018-11-20 14:00:41
```

And the result will be by name, code and for each of them the MAX of the `date` field and if the dates are the same, filter by `id` too:

```
ID  Name    Stock   Code    Date
<---------------------------------------------->
120 GAME_0088     212   WK1 2018-11-20 19:32:13
123 GAME_0011     1     WK1 2018-11-20 16:12:16
```

My query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM games
WHERE name IN ('GAME_0088', 'GAME_0011')
AND code IN ('WK1')
AND date IN (SELECT max(date) FROM stocks GROUP BY name)
ORDER BY id desc
```

But returns:

```
ID  Name    Stock   Code    Date
<---------------------------------------------->
123 GAME_0011   1   WK1 2018-11-20 16:12:16
109 GAME_0088   21  WK1 2018-11-20 19:32:13
```

What is wrong? How can I filter by the MAX ID too?

Comment: The two entries for ACK1134 both have the same date/time value so what it picks as the MAX is going to be arbitrary - there's no way to distinguish which is the biggest date

Comment: You can order by 2 columns just fine I believe, without creating a whole lot of extra sql to do it. `ORDER BY id DESC, Date DESC`. Note that date is a reserved word in sql, and you will need to add backticks (`) to the column name if that's the actual column name for the date field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Derived table, you can get the maximum value of `ID` for a specific group of `name` and `code`. Join back to the `games` table using this information to get the row corresponding to maximum date.

```
SELECT g.*
FROM games AS g 
JOIN 
( SELECT name, code, MAX(ID) AS max_id
  FROM games 
  GROUP BY name, code
) AS dt ON dt.name = g.name AND 
           dt.code = g.code AND 
           dt.max_id = g.ID 
WHERE g.name IN ('ACK1134', 'ACK1159')
  AND g.code IN ('CD23')
ORDER BY g.ID desc
```

Comment: But it returns the same, 3 results. I need to filter by ID too.

Comment: @gtx911 what do you mean filtering by `ID`. Your problem statement does not clearly explain this.

Comment: I have updated. I need to filter by id field too because could be that there are two dates equals.

Comment: I think OP means that if there are two dates which could be the max date, then it should distinguish between them by selecting the one with the largest ID, instead of selecting one arbitrarily. This is the scenario for the entries with the name ACK1134 in the sample data. I don't believe your revised code above now involves the date in its decision-making process.

Comment: @ADyson I know but there is an implicit assumption in my solution that higher `ID` means higher `Date` value.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya but what if the dates are _not_ equal, I think then you'll just select the max ID anyway? And that could potentially be the wrong result.

Comment: @gtx911 please confirm if the assumption I stated above is fair enough or not ? Generally, any new entry in the table is for the latest date and has the highest ID value at that time

Comment: @ADyson as I am stating, that highest `ID` generally means highest `Date` value only in most systems. I have asked OP for further clarification in previous comment.

Comment: True, as you say, it depends on the reality of how the data is created and updated.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya But you have replaced max_date by id and I want both. First, by max_date and then, by id because could be that there will be two same dates

Comment: @gtx911 please understand what I am trying to say. I am simply asking that will there be a case when the highest ID value will not have maximum Date ?